# syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is what im having syntax errors on. I tried following an example website, but I guess I must've put something in the wrong  place or didnt add something. If someone could show me what i might've done wrong that would be great.

```
<div align ="center">
    <h3>Create Your Project</h3>

      <%= simple_form_for @createproject, :url => createprojects_url :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
          <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
          <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
          <%= f.input :tripdates, :required => true %>
          <%= f.input :teamname, :required => true %>
          <%= f.input :teamleader, :required => true %>
          <%= f.input :tree, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :solar, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :water, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :goats, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :kids, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :house, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :roof, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :latrine, as: :check_boxes %>
          <%= f.input :build, as: :check_boxes %>
          <% f.button :submit %>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> simple_form_for @createproject, :url => createprojects_url, :html
>   => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f|

you've missed a comma